# Adding ripple background effect on white background

Tags: android

I want to add ripple effect on my recycler view item,`android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`
 I am able to aceive the ripple effect but the problem is i want to have ripple effect on white background. Here is my xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:background="@color/white"
android:padding="6dp">...
.....SOME MORE CODE....
</LinearLayout>
```

I can not have two android backgrounds so how can i achieve ripple effect on white background

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RippleDrawable` class for this. Below is the code :

```
RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = (RippleDrawable)view.getBackground(); // It will assume bg is a RippleDrawable

int[][] states = new int[][] { new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled} };
int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE }; // sets the ripple color to blue

ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
rippleDrawable.setColor(colorStateList);
```

If you are comfortable with xml you can use the below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#FF000000"> 

    <!-- the normal bg color -->
    <item>
        <color android:color="#FFDDDDAA" />
    </item>

    <!-- make sure the ripple doesn't exceed the bounds -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: This will give you a ripple effect on sdk v21 and bigger. if you want to add a ripple effect on older versions, the easiest way is adding a library

Answer (score 0):

In the layout for the recycler item view use foreground and background

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
.....SOME MORE XML.....
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Then use the code below (from Aniket Jadhav) in the constructor of your RecyclerViewItemViewHolder (but with getForeground instead of getBackground)

```
public RecyclerViewItemViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    mView = view;

    android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = (android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable)view.getForeground();

    int[][] states = new int[][] { new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled} };
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.GRAY };

    android.content.res.ColorStateList colorStateList = new android.content.res.ColorStateList(states, colors);
    rippleDrawable.setColor(colorStateList);
}
```